# ...поймёт (?) поражение потерплено (?) что сделает (?)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, спп, двоеточие

Какие знаки препинания поставить?

Есть ли слово "потерплено"?

**Когда безумный кровавый маньяк поймёт (?) поражение потерплено (?) что сделает (?) застрелится или нажмёт красную кнопку?**

Даже если слова нет такого... допустим, что есть! Какие знаки ставить в такого рода конструкциях? Если хотите, замените на "случилось" или на "имеет место".

Answer (score 2):

В Викисловаре есть страдательное причастие [**потерпленный**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) без указания на краткие формы.

На сайте classes.ru, который ссылается на Толковый словарь русского языка С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой, представлены все формы глагола [**ПОТЕРПЕТЬ**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ozhegov-term-25532.htm), в том числе и ***потерплено***.

Может, где-то и встречается это слово, но в Нацкорпусе русского языка нет ни одного примера с ним. Обычно говорят и пишут в действительном залоге, обозначая действие субъекта: *потерпел поражение, потерпевший поражение.*

Если не рассматривать значение отдельных слов, не придираться к структуре и, на мой взгляд, разговорному стилю, это предложение можно оформить так:

***Когда безумный кровавый маньяк поймёт: поражение потерплено, что сделает – застрелится или нажмёт красную кнопку?*** (Я бы добавил местоимение: *...что **он** сделает*...)

P. S. При необходимости могу предоставить ссылки на правила.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью только бессоюзной связи трудно выразить эту мысль. Поэтому предложение  желательно редактировать, от этого оно не будет менее эмоциональными и выразительным:

***Когда безумный кровавый маньяк поймёт, что  это поражение, то что он сдЕлает – застрелится или нажмёт красную кнОпку?***

И уж в любом случае не следует писать "поражение потерплено", если краткая форма не обозначена в словаре. а само сочетание в литературе не используется.

Тире и запятая заменяют друг друга в подобных случаях (об этом сказано у Розенталя), но здесь нежелательно интонационное предупреждение, то есть остановка голоса и предупредительная пауза. Поэтому тире более уместно.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, что более правильным было бы поставить двоеточие после "сделает" и интонационное тире перед "или".

**Когда безумный кровавый маньяк поймёт: поражение потерплено, что сделает: застрелится - или нажмёт красную кнопку?**

И даже если "то сделает что" написать, то тоже двоеточие нужно:

**Когда безумный кровавый маньяк поймёт: поражение потерплено, то сделает что: застрелится - или нажмёт красную кнопку?**

Может, эксперты поправят. Но мне кажется, что двоеточие говорит нам, что после него будет раскрытие информации. И здесь как раз информация раскрывается.

Comment: Я обдумывал разные варианты, в том числе с двоеточием после "сделает". Но в одном предложении желательно не использовать этот знак дважды. У Розенталя есть параграф [ДВОЕТОЧНИЕ – ТИРЕ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189), где говорится о частом параллельном использовании этих знаков, например: *Сколько мне тогда было (:  –) девятнадцать или двадцать?*